# Eslint is watching file that are in eslintignore

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, eslint

I have a TypeScript project, which is bundling by Webpack. And now I want to add some Eslint. But there's one problem - Eslint watch compiled files even if they in the **.eslintignore**

**.eslintignore:**

```
./app
```

[image]

As you see, Eslint tried to look inside **app** directory, but there was an error, because I exlude this directory in the **tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "app/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Eslint do not watch **node_modules**, but they are not in **.eslintignore**. But it watch **app** directory, which is in **.eslintignore**. How can I fix it?

---

**EDIT:**

This is the structure of my code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we don't need the dot `.` in front of `app` based on the document I think we just need to leave it as `app`:

`.eslintignore`:

```js
app
// or blob pattern
app/**/*.js
```

Comment: If I remove this dot Eslint will look only at files in `./` directory and not deeper. I mean, without the dot `./views/app/appView.ts` is not seen

Comment: Not sure what you meant but can you share your project structure?

Comment: Do you want just to ignore all js files in the static dir as screenshot above?

Comment: All files in `app` directory. This directory is created by Webpack

Comment: Yes, thank you. But as I understand from the documentation simply adding `app` should also work. Why it's not?